# checking if a list in a text file already exists and appending to it

Tags: python, list, append

So from this:

```
Lucy:4
Henry:8
Henry:9
Lucy:9
```

To this

```
Lucy: 4,9
Henry: 8,9
```

this is now fixed thank you

Comment: Opening a file in append mode won't help, you're going to have to overwrite the original file.

Comment: Why you are printing comma, before join()?  `file.write(key + ':' + ',' + ',' + ','.join(value))`

Comment: much easier store as  json  and do dict lookups

Answer (score 1):

Very straight forward solution might be like this: (If you don't want to use defaultdict)

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    dic = {}
    for line in f:
        key,value = line.strip().split(':')
        dic.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)

with open('output','a') as f:
    for key,value in dic.items():
        f.write(key + ':' + ','.join(value) + '\n')
```

***UPDATE***

I have fixed your code, and you need to change this lines:

1. Remove the following lines, they are useless here.

   ```
   file = open(class_number, 'a') #opens the file in 'append' mode so you don't delete all the information
   file.write(str(name + ",")) #writes the name and ":" to file
   file.write(str(score)) #writes the score to file
   file.write('\n')#writes the score to the file
   file.close()#safely closes the file to save the information
   ```
2. You are using the wrong delimiter.

   ```
   key,value= line.split(",")
   ```

Change this to below:

```
    key,value= line.strip().split(":")
```

This will fix your error.

N.B. Here, strip() is there to remove spaces and newlines.

3. Don't really know, why you are prining the commas.

   ```
   file.write(key + ':' + ',' + ',' + ','.join(value))
   ```

   Change this to below:

   ```
   file.write(key + ':' + ','.join(value) + '\n')
   ```
4. One thing, you are reading and writing from the same file. In that case, you should read all at once if you need to write to the same file. But if you use a separate file, you are just fine with this code.

Comment: I have implemented this with my other code, but it says " for key,value in dic.iteritems():
NameError: name 'dic' is not defined"

Comment: You might have missed something (dictionary initialization). The code runs well on my side.

Comment: What is dictionary initialisation? Sorry I am new to this, do i have to import a module?

Comment: `dic.setdefault(key, []).append(value)` would save you the if/else construct.

Comment: @timgeb, I know, as I have included it in my answer.  I thought, as a newbee,  OP might prefer this approach.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque this is a method on the regular dictionary, not a defaultdict.

Comment: Sorry I am still very confused it says

Comment: for key,value in dic.iteritems(): NameError: name 'dic' is not defined"

Comment: @M.Weiss did you forget the line `dic = {}`?

Comment: No! That's the line where I though It had been defined

Comment: My suggestion is to run this code in a separate file to convince yourself that it runs and understand what it does. When you are comfortable, integrate it with your code. Best of luck.

Comment: Ah i hadn't indented the second part, so now it runs but says this error "    for key,value in dic.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'"

Comment: @M.Weiss it's just `items` in Python3.

Comment: But atleast it now runs!

Comment: check this line `for key,value in dic.items():`

Comment: II run it and it produces this:                                                                          Maya,0
Maya:,,0
Even if my score was not 0, so now I have gone backwards :(

Comment: Actually, it is quite impossible to comment on this info. You better edit your question with all these information and your updated code.

Comment: You are using the wrong delimiter, use `line.split(":")` instead of `line.split(",")`

Comment: @M.Weiss, I just fixed your code, and now it should run fine.

Comment: It now runs without error, but nothing at all is saving to the text file (class class_number)?

Comment: What is *class_number* here? a variable? You should use your input filename here. And then use a different name for the output file. See my initial answer.

Comment: class_number is the name of the text file

Comment: I have to use the same file because class_number changes depending on the users input and then creates a text file

Comment: if `class_number` is the name of the file, you should quote it like this, `'class_number'`. Again, see my initial answer.

Comment: I have updated the question again, thank you for your help so far!

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1:

Best way to do so is first read all data in dictionary and finally dump it to file.

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

def add_item(classname,source):    
    for name,score in source:
        result[name].append(score)
    with open(classname,'w') as c:
        for key,val in result.items():
            c.write('{}: {}'.format(key,','.join(val))
```

### Solution 2:

for each request, you have to real whole the file and then rewrite it.:

```
def add_item(classname,name,score):
    result={item.spilt(':')[0],item.spilt(':')[1] for item in open(classname,'r').readlines()]
    result[name].append(score)
    with open(classname,'w') as c:
            for key,val in result.items():
                c.write('{}: {}'.format(key,','.join(val))
```

Comment: But i'm not sure this will work because I am getting the data from lines in the file as opposed to getting them from a dictionary in the code?