# Code doesn't save to file

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have code which runs but doesn't save anything to the text file?

```
def saving_multiple_scores():
    with open(class_number) as file:
          dic = {}
          for line in file:
              key, value = line.strip().split(':')
              dic.setdefault(key, []).append(value)
              file.write(dic)

    with open(class_number, 'a') as file:
        for key, value in dic.items():
            file.write(key + ':' + ','.join(value) + '\n')
            print(dic)
```

It should check if the name is already in the file, and if so: append a score
and if not then create a new list with the score.

However nothing is saving at all.
Python, IDLE V3.4.2

I am new to this so any help is appreciated

Comment: try initailising your dictionary outside the fucntion definition

Comment: Nope still does not work

Comment: is the file empty before you run it?

Answer (score 0):

the first `with` is not working because the file is empty and the `for` loop iterates over lines in file

The default for mode for `open` (see https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) is read only so `file.write(dic)` won't work

Comment: OK, What do you suggest I do to fix this?

Comment: It's hard to figure out what you are really trying to do

Comment: Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35100461/checking-if-a-list-in-a-text-file-already-exists-and-appending-to-it/35100558?noredirect=1#comment57923660_35100558

Comment: I would propose to first create dict by reading a file, and then open it again  and write from scratch

Comment: What do you mean? Could you provide some code to demonstrate this?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Pawel’s suggestion, here is what you do to fix your code:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def saving_multiple_scores():
    with open(class_number, 'r') as f: # don't use file
          data = defaultdict(list)
          for line in f:
              line = line.strip() 
              if not line:
                  continue # skip over any blank lines in the file
              key, value = line.split(':')
              data[key.strip()].append(value.strip())
              # file.write removed because we don't write in readmode

    with open(class_number, 'a') as f:
        # using 'a' mode will append the score lists
        # to the end of the file
        # to overwrite the file completely, use 'w'
        for key, value in data.items():
            line = '%s:%s\n' % (key, ','.join(value),)
            f.write(line)
            print '%s' % line,
```

Sample input file:

```
alice:1
alice:2
alice:3
bob:1
alice:4
bob:2
```

Sample output file:

```
alice:1
alice:2
alice:3
bob:1
alice:4
bob:2
bob:1,2
alice:1,2,3,4
```